# EditText with inputType and textAlignment makes Soft Keyboard hide EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, keyboard

If I have a layout like this (this is a sample version of my layout, mine looks similar but a bit more complex. I ran the all my tests in this sample code as well):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"

            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you just create a new project and put this as your layout, when you start the application the `EditText` will be focused and the first time you click on it, the keyboard will appear and make the `EditText` go up and be over the keyboard. But if you cancel this keyboard (with android's default back button) and click in the `EditText` again, it will be behind the keyboard.

If you take out `android:textAlignment="center"` OR `android:inputType="number"` it works perfectly, but with both it conflicts. Any ideas of what should I do? I've already tried to set the `inputType` programatically but it didn't work anyway.

**EDIT:** EXAMPLE FOTO ADDED

[image]

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for me, I've tested on my Galaxy tab and my Google Pixel. What are you testing it on, can you post a picture?

Comment: @Drew, I'm testing on my Moto G 3rd Gen. I'll make some Virtual Devices to test on, but if it isn't working in my fisical phone I think it could be at least a problem for the ones that have the same device as me.

Comment: Could you please edit your original post to include a picture? Just to make sure I'm testing it right. When the app opens, I click the `EditText` view, click back, then click `EditText` again?

Comment: @Drew, I've added the example foto...

Comment: Thanks! Could you also post your code, are you doing anything programmatically, maybe with onBackPressed()?

Comment: @Drew Not at all, it is simply a default onCreate() that Android Studio creates for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` into the activity section of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity>
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
</activity>
```

Comment: I'll try this in an Emulated Device, because in my Physical one it didn't work... May be my phone. I've already tried to Clean, Uninstall and Reinstall the app and nothing... If it work in the emulator, I'll accept your answer anyway. You've been so helpful about my problem

Comment: I'm busting out my Note 4 to test...problem is the battery is dead. Give me a few moments and I'll see what I can do. What API is your Moto G 3rd Gen on? I'll edit this post as I continue testing.

Comment: My phone is API 23, I'll run tests in a Emulator with API 22 now

Comment: It worked fine on my Note 4, however I saw that each time I clicked `EditText`, the `Navbar` would disappear. When I edited my `AndroidManifest.xml` to include `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, the `Navbar` stopped disappearing. Please try my updated code. Thanks

Comment: YES! Uhul! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

have you tried this?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Why `getActivity()`? The main page is already an Activity, shouldn't be `MainActivity.this`? If so, I've tried but it didn't work.

Comment: yeap use just getWindow(). It is just an habit because I use getActivity() in fragments frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" to your activity in Manifest file. The activity where the EditText is on.